# grunt livereload with WordPress and WAMP/MAMP server?

Tags: php, gruntjs

[Existing posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108782/grunt-livereload-with-wordpress) dealing with grunt livereload and WordPress development explain that you still need WAMP/MAMP to serve PHP and MySQL. You can't just go with the barebones server which reloads index.html on port 35729 in all the basic grunt livereload examples. I get that.

But as I understand it I've got to get my grunt livereload to point to the same port as WAMP, otherwise they're operating in different universes and no livereloading goodness is going to occur.

I guess that means setting grunt up like this:

```
      options: {
          livereload: 80
      },
```

But if I do that grunt complains

> Fatal error. Port 80 is already in use

Equally, if I fire up grunt first then WAMP, it's Apache that complains that the port is already in use.

So how do you get them to be on the same page?

PS In WordPress my functions.php includes this, per suggested setups documented elsewhere, not sure if this is also part of the problem:

```
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', '::1'))) {
    wp_register_script('livereload', 'http://localhost/myproject/livereload.js?snipver=1', null, false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('livereload');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The livereload port is used by a web socket. When Grunt do the task a message is send to the web page to say "reload you".
It's the same as "the basic grunt livereload examples". A server delivers html (and other files) by http on port 80 ans the livereload server listen on an other port (35729 if you want).
I didn't see that is your problem :-/.

I think you PHP code simply add `<script src="http://localhost/myproject/livereload.js?snipver=1"></script>` on your page when you access to the site from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Apache (in WAMP) is running on port 80, so you can't use that for livereload. Do something like this:

```
// functions.php
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', '::1'))) {
    wp_register_script('livereload', 'http://localhost:9000/myproject/livereload.js?snipver=1', null, false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('livereload');
}

// Gruntfile.js
options: {
    livereload: 9000
},
```

It doesn't have to be port 9000, just something other than 80.